# c++ boost asio async_read_some read all data

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I try to get by boost Socket Server some POST data. To read it I use **async_read_some**, I understand that Server get data by blocks, then I recall read method, but how I can know when it's read all data?...
Example of code:

private:

```
    void do_handshake()
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server,
            [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& error)
            {
                if (!error)
                {
                    do_read();
                }
            });
    }

    void do_read()
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_),
            [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)
            {
                if (!ec)
                {
                    do_read();
/*Something do with receive data */

write("send answer");

                }

            });
    }
    void do_write(std::string SendData)
    {



        auto self(shared_from_this());
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(SendData),
            [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                std::size_t /*length*/)
            {
                if (!ec)
                {
                    do_read();
                }
            });
    }
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: In general, you don't. You're supposed to implement a protocol that delimits the boundary between messages. In HTTP, you'd parse the data as a string and look for things like newlines, HTTP tags, etc. I'd go and read about HTTP in detail, or better yet use Boost.Beast.

Comment: I’l parse http after read all data

Comment: So you read the HTTP header until `\r\n\r\n`. Though boost::beast already does that.

Comment: yes. and It will be header, but how read body? there no content-length in header.

Comment: If `connection: keep-alive`, then there will be either `content-length` or `transfer-encoding: chunked`. Otherwise read until EOF.